# Cropped image from the image picker

Tags: android

I am trying to get a cropped image from the image picker. I can choose an image and see the cropped rectangle. But after cropping returned to my activity, my `uri` is always null... "onActivityResult" will not be called.

**My code:**

```
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                int imageX = iv.getMeasuredWidth();
                int imageY = iv.getMeasuredHeight();

                pickImageIntent.setType("image/*");
                pickImageIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                pickImageIntent.putExtra("outputX", imageX);
                pickImageIntent.putExtra("outputY", imageY);
                pickImageIntent.putExtra("aspectX", imageX);
                pickImageIntent.putExtra("aspectY", imageY);
                pickImageIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
                pickImageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
                startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent,REQ_CODE_PICK_GALLERY);
            }
        });
```

**also calling**

```
pickImageIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

**or**

```
@Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        iv.setImageURI(uri);
    }
```

does not work either...

**These are my permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

**I also tried:**

```
pickImageIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.toString());
pickImageIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

and get the bitmap in `onActivityResult` works, but the `imagesize` is too small. It feels like

```
pickImageIntent.putExtra("outputX", imageX);
pickImageIntent.putExtra("outputY", imageY);
```

is being ignored, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the "onActivityResult", not the "onResume".
Here is a sample that may helps you

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```